# IL code to call method with out parameter

Tags: c#, cil, emit, out-parameters, ilgenerator

I want to IL generate a dynamic method

```
delegate ArraySegment<byte> X(MyClass mc);
```

that calls a method of the signature on `mc` and returns its `out` parameter.

```
MethodInfo methInf = aClass.GetMethod("Y",
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, 
    null, new[] { typeof(ArraySegment<byte>).MakeByRefType() }, null);
```

but I don't know how to handle the out parameter. Here's the code I have so far.

```
DynamicMethod dm = new DynamicMethod("X", typeof(ArraySegment<byte>),
                                     new[] { typeof(MyClass) });
ILGenerator il = dm.GetILGenerator();

il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, methInf, null);
```

What's needed to make the out param work?

Comment: Just to clarify, your question is about how to emit a **call** to a method featuring an `out` parameter?

Comment: Since the parameter is already a ref type, you *should* just have to load the parameter (which *is* a reference) - whether that is arg0 or arg1 depends on instance vs static

Comment: `ref` and `out` are actually identical to the CLR. They only differ by how the compiler enforces that code sets an `out` before the method returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @MarcGravell (also for your deleted answer, which was of great help, as it spells out what you hint at in your comment to my question) and [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx), which helped me by compiling c# code to CIL, so I could just peek at that.

So here's the final, working code:

```
LocalBuilder local = il.DeclareLocal(typeof(ArraySegment<byte>));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloca, local);
il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, methInf, null);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Pop);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, local.LocalIndex);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

Invoking this is 10 times faster than doing `methodInfo.Invoke(...)` (on a `methodInfo` object that was created only once, of course).